# Sharing a Queue instance between different modules

Tags: python, multithreading, global

I am new to Python and I would like to create what is a 'global static variable', my thread-safe and process-safe queue, between threads/processes created in different modules.
I read from the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules) that the concept of a global variable is created using a third module, that I will call as cfg, which defines and initializes my global queue.
I have a problem sharing the instance of this objects between my modules because I tried to print the **repr**() function over the shared queue imported from the cfg module, inside my other modules that import it, and it shows that they are different instances. It seems that every time I try to import a module a new instance is created and passed to the module who imports it.

Main.py:

```
import GatewayManager
if __name__ == '__main__':
    GatewayManager.initialize()
    doSomething()
```

GatewayManager.py:

```
import multiprocessing
import queue
import threading

def initialize():
    # Multiprocessing or Threading
    global isMonoCPU
    isMonoCPU = multiprocessing.cpu_count() == 1

    global sharedQueue
    sharedQueue = multiprocessing.Queue() if not isMonoCPU else queue.Queue()
    print("gateway: ", sharedQueue.__repr__())
```

otherModules.py:

```
import GatewayManager

# Some module write on the queue
GatewayManager.sharedQueue.put(variable)

# Some read from the queue
GatewayManager.sharedQueue.get()
print("driver: ", GatewayManager.sharedQueue.__repr__())
```

Comment: If you want to share state between processes, you want a database. Not necessarily a relational one nor even a persistant one (something like Redis might just be enough) but it has to handle concurrency.

Comment: wrt/ your "every time I try to import a module a new instance is created " problem, it's just impossible to answer without a MCVE.

Comment: I added a MCV example. I tried to create an inizialization function inside the main but it's not working, it says no module GatewayManager has no attribute sharedQueue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
# GatewayManager.py:

...

def initialize():
    global sharedQueue
    # ...
    sharedQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    # ...
```

Your `GatewayManager` module  don't have a `sharedQueue` attribute until it's `initialize()` function is called., so if any other module tries to use `GatewayManager.sharedQueue` before `GatewayManager.initialize()` has been called then of course you'll get this error. And since `GatewayManager.initialize()` blindly rebinds `sharedQueue` on each call, if you call it again from another module then you lose the already created queue and gets a new one.

What you want is to make sure your sharedqueue is created once and only once,  and that it will be created whatever happens. The solution (well, one solution at least - but it's a known working solution) here is to  proxy all `GatewayManager.sharedQueue.whatever` access thru functions that will take care of initializing the queue if and when needed.

```
# gateway_manager.py

class _QueueProxy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._queueimp = None

    @property
    def _queue(self):
        if self._queueimp is None:
            isMonoCPU = multiprocessing.cpu_count() == 1
            self._queueimp = queue.Queue() if isMonoCPU else multiprocessing.Queue() 

        return self._queueimp

    def get(self, *args, **kw):
        return self._queue.get(*args, **kw)

    def put(self, *args, **kw):
        return self._queue.put(*args, **kw)

   # etc... only expose public methods and attributes of course


# and now our `shared_queue` instance    
shared_queue = _QueueProxy()
```

And now you can  safely (well almost - the queue creation is not atomic so you may have race conditions) use `gateway_manager.shared_queue` from any module without having to care about initialization.

Of course if you have two distinct processes (I'm not talking about `multiprocessing.Process` here) you will still have two distinct queues but I assume you already understood this (and if not please read Jean-Paul's answer).

Comment: I understood your point and that's why I created the initialize() function. I call the function as the first statement in my main.py only once (at least this is what I think). The other processes and created and use the sharedQueue by the doSomething() function below the Initialize() function.

Comment: Sorry but your "MCVE" is neither C ("complete") nor V ("verifiable"), we don't have the slightest idea of the program flow etc, so you can't expect a better answer.  This being said your `initialize` function is not safe (you should not rely on the client code doing the "right thing" here - it's your job to make it safe), and in your "otherModule" example all we have are top-level statements so obviously if you import those modules before you initialized your queue it just cannot work.

Comment: I am sorry but I managed to get it to work, the program was okay but I thought it wasn't seeing the output of the repr() functions on the queues: they had different values but the queue was shared. I thought it was a good oracle to see whether the queue instance was unique but it wasn't. I think at low level memory, depending on the context on which you fork a process it can use the same space of memory of the father memory or copy in another location and link the spaces together. I am not sure but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

A `multiprocessing.Queue` is shared between the process that creates it (let's call it "Parent") and processes created by Parent (let's call them "Children").

Here is an example of some processes that do not have this relationship:

```
$ python myprogram.py &
$ python myprogram.py &
```

The shell is the Parent of these two Children.  The shell did not create the `multiprocessing.Queue`, though, so it will not be shared by the two children.  Instead, they will each create their own.  This may be shared with *their* children but not with each other.

You can easily observe this behavior:

```
$ cat queuedemo.py 
from time import sleep
from os import getpid
from sys import argv

from multiprocessing import Queue

q = Queue()

if argv[1:]:
    q.put(getpid())
    sleep(60)
else:
    print(getpid(), q.get())
exarkun@baryon:/tmp/queue$ python queuedemo.py foo & python queuedemo.py 
[1] 28249
```

The second process never manages to read anything from the queue.  However, if you give the two process the Parent-Child relationship...

```
$ cat queuedemo.py 
from os import getpid

from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing.process import Process

q = Queue()
q.put(getpid())

def child():
    print(getpid(), q.get())

p = Process(target=child)
p.start()
p.join()
exarkun@baryon:/tmp/queue$ python queuedemo.py 
(28469, 28467)
exarkun@baryon:/tmp/queue$
```

Notice that the `q.get()` call succeeds and that the pid put into the queue is different from the pid of the process that gets it out.

Somewhat necessarily, this also extends to processes with Parent-Descendant and Sibling relationships.

So:

- Globals are only shared within a single process
- The multiprocessing module provides tools to share state between processes that are properly related to each other.

If you want to share state between processes without this relationship, there are a variety of other options - and the best one will depend a bit more on what kind of state you have to share and what your sharing patterns look like (neither of which you've included in your question).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understood the concept (I guess) of your reply. In my case the main.py module which is launched with the python shell is the one that creates the other processes or threads. I think then that all my processes are related and that I can use a sharedQueue between them.

Comment: How does it create the other processes?

Comment: I got it to work, the processes were creating after the call of the initialize(), in the doSomething() function by creating a Process instance and passing a function to run when starting the process. (the standard way I think, without overriding the class).